Commenting out code with PHP & JS causing bug
This code seems to comment out the alert line out, any idea why?
If I remove "//test" then it seems to work though.
Not sure if it's a PHP or JS Bug or it's meant to uncomment the line below also?
<script>
//test <? //test ?>
alert("test");
</script>

In the page source shows as:
<script>
//test alert("test");
</script>


Probably something with how the line endings are processed. I'm still not sure why, but if you add another line before the alert, it's fine. https://3v4l.org/EV7eT

Why does

Work fine then? (Remove the first "//test")

It seems like there's a problem with html interpreter, what browser are you using?

@anyber Yes I noticed this also, I think it's a bug because if you remove the js commented code it works too.

@VanHudsonGalvoso does the same on both Chrome and Firefox

@user2643679 can you check your php.ini and search for short_open_tag, If it is on try to change it to off like this short_open_tag=Off .

@VanHudsonGalvoso Don't think that matters since using <?php instead of <? gives the same results.

@user2643679 when short_open_tag is turned off <? will not work. just try to turn it off then try again.

I'll write an answer so I can explain it more clearly.

@VanHudsonGalvoso I used the full tag in my 3v4l code, and it's the same issue. The short tags won't make a difference here.

I knew I'd seen this problem before, had to remember the keywords to find the question again. Hopefully the duplicates helps a bit.

I'll just leave here an answer just in case.
If short_open_tag in your php.ini is on you can use <? aside from <?php
So in your case, php will interpret this
<script>  //test <? //test ?>  alert("test"); </script>
as
<script>  //test alert("test"); </script>
since <? //test ?> is just a php comment and
the browser does not apply any formatting or line breaks to the JavaScript code contained within the <script> tag
so js code //test alert('test'); appears on a single line, even though it's written with line breaks in your HTML source.
